How can I ignore first x columns of the line with Git diff?
We have our COBOL-Sources now in GIT-repositories. During development nearly all devs are removing the cobol leading line squence numbers. So the git diff is showing all lines as changed.
I want that a diff of these files would show just the ====> CHANGED line:
000201 PROCEDURE DIVISION USING VKT1511
000202                          VKT1519
000203                          LI-DUMMY
000204                          LI-DUMMY
000205                          LI-KKONTO
000206                          BS0397-SEGMENT
000207                          TAB-KONTEN
000208                          TAB-LIMITE
000209                          TAB-KUNDE
000210                          BS0798.
000211*
000212*    == VORLAUF ==
000213*

       PROCEDURE DIVISION USING VKT1511
                                VKT1519
                                LI-DUMMY
                                LI-DUMMY
                                LI-KKONTO
                                BS0397-SEGMENT
                                TAB-KONTEN
                                TAB-LIMITE
                                TAB-KUNDE
                   ===========> CHANGED.
      *
      *    == VORLAUF ==
      *

I don't care if I have to use standard GIT DIFF or TortoiseDiff or whatever.

You can define a diff driver -- doc in git help gitattributes -- to run a specific program for your cobol files.
A quick way to view a diff after stripping the 7 first columns:
diff <(cut -c8- "$file1") <(cut -c8- "$file2")

# you can actually use 'git diff' as a command line diff viewer:
git diff --no-index <(cut -c8- "$file1") <(cut -c8- "$file2")

You can stick that command in a script, and use that script as a diff driver:
# ~/bin/cobol-diff:
#!/bin/bash

old_file=$2
new_file=$5

git diff --no-index <(cut -c8- "$old_file") <(cut -c8- "$new_file")

# .git/config or global .gitconfig:
[diff "cobol-diff"]
    command = path/to/cobol-diff

# .gitattributes:
.cobol diff=cobol-diff

Obviously: you may adapt the script or use any other suitable diff viewer (including a graphical one)

[update] : added --no-index to git diff. --no-index is actually implicit when one of the compared files is outside of the repository, and <( ... ) syntax in bash is actually replaced with /dev/fd/<xxx> which is outside the repo.
